# flutter problem: how to manage height in tabbar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

### I have a problem this that in my android device cwctv page is working but in IOS Device giving height error,so how to set height for every device.

I have a problem this that in my android device cwctv page is working but in IOS Device giving height error,so how to set height for every device.
I have a problem this that in my android device cwctv page is working but in IOS Device giving height error,so how to set height for every device.
this is my cwctv page.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.5,      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: SideBar(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18.0),
        child: Container(
          height: 80,
          width: 80,
          child: FittedBox(
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              focusColor: Colors.transparent,
              backgroundColor: selectBlueColor,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
              },
              materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/home_icon.png',
              ),
              elevation: 1.0,
              highlightElevation: 2,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * (10 / 100),
          child: BottomNavBarTV()),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0,right: 16,bottom: 4,top: 0),
              child: SizedBox(
                  height: 60,
                  child:  TextField( keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              print("tab on cwctv page $cwcTvTab");
                            });
                          },
                          // controller: cwcTvTab == 3 ?searchImageQuery : cwcTvTab == 2 ?searchPdfQuery : cwcTvTab == 1 ? searchAudioQuery : searchVideoQuery,
                          controller: searchQuery,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                            ),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: const Color(0xFFF1F2F6),
                            hintText: 'Search for Wellness Tips & Tricks',
                            suffixIcon: const Icon(
                              Icons.search_outlined,
                              color: Color(0xFF444444),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                     )),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 70.0),
            child: TestScreen(widget.selectTab),
          ),

          // CwcTVPageChanger(),
          // VideoComponent(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is my tab screen page.

```
import 'package:cwc/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/CwcTv/components/images/image_document.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/CwcTv/components/podcast/podcast_list.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/CwcTv/components/slides/slide_component.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/CwcTv/components/videos/video_component.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/CwcTv/cwc_tv.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:cwc/constants/constant_functions.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  int selectedPage;

  TestScreen(this.selectedPage);

  @override
  State<TestScreen> createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin, WidgetsBindingObserver {
  void _handleTabSelection() {
    setState(() {});
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        // _tabSection(context, widget.selectedPage,controller!),
        _tabSection(context, widget.selectedPage),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Widget _tabSection(BuildContext context, var selectedPage) {
  return DefaultTabController(
    initialIndex: selectedPage,
    length: 4,
    child: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          TabBar(
            indicatorColor: Colors.black,
            onTap: (v) {

              cwcTvTab = v;
             
            },
            isScrollable: true,
            // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            labelColor: Colors.black,
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                child: Text(
                  'Video',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text(
                  'Podcast',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text(
                  'Documents',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text(
                  'Images',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 282,
            // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 205,
            // height: double.infinity,
            child:
                TabBarView( physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    children: [
              VideoComponent(),
              PodcastList(),
              SlideComponent(),
              ImageDocument(),
            ]),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

this is my android Device's screenshot.
[image]

this is my IOS Device's screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Why don't you wrap the child to `Singlechildscrollview`?

Comment: @mikenlanggio where "Why don't you wrap the child to Singlechildscrollview? "?

Comment: Try wrap `body` like this: `body: Singlechildscrollview(child: Stack(...))`

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 options you can use, first try with indicator like this one:

```
TabBar(
        indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 5.0),
          insets: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:16.0)
        ),
        indicatorColor: Colors.black,
        onTap: (v) {

          cwcTvTab = v;
         
        },
        isScrollable: true,
        // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        labelColor: Colors.black,
        tabs: [
          Tab(
            child: Text(
              'Video',
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
          Tab(
            child: Text(
              'Podcast',
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
          Tab(
            child: Text(
              'Documents',
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Tab(
            child: Text(
              'Images',
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Or you can just wrap it with a container.

```
    PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(10),
      child: Container(
        height: 50,
        child: TabBar(
          indicatorColor: Colors.black,
          isScrollable: true,
          labelColor: Colors.black,
          tabs: [
            Tab(
              child: Text(
                'Video',
              ),
            ),
            Tab(
              child: Text(
                'Podcast',
              ),
            ),
            Tab(
              child: Text(
                'Documents',
              ),
            ),
            Tab(
              child: Text(
                'Images',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score -1):

Tabbar has height is 48px. it correct with me

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how this answer attempts to solve the problem?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).